# Extracting text from file to use as file name

Tags: unix, grep, text-processing

Given a file, for example:

```
TABLE='SampleTableName';
Field1=1.0000;
Field2=1.2500;
Field3=1.5000;
Field4=1.7500;
Field5=3.5000;
```

I'd like to grep the text within the single quotes and set it as the same file's name and retain the rest as the contents.

So in the above example, the output file name would be **SampleTableName** and the contents would be

```
Field1=1.0000;
Field2=1.2500;
Field3=1.5000;
Field4=1.7500;
Field5=3.5000;
```

How can I do that? Any help / guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `bash` and `sed`:

```
source file.txt
sed 1d file.txt > "$TABLE"
```

Output to file `SampleTableName`:

```
Field1=1.0000;
Field2=1.2500;
Field3=1.5000;
Field4=1.7500;
Field5=3.5000;
```

Update:

```
for i in tblFile*; do
  source "$i"
  sed 1d "$i" > "$TABLE"
done
```

Comment: If there are multiple files in the same folder with files (All file names starting with tblFile*) with a similar structure, how could I bulk rename all of them based on the TABLE='<>' value? Sorry if I didn't mention that in the main question.

Comment: I've updated my answer.